# Custom Post Types in main index? (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using the Thematic framework along with custom post type ui plug in to make custom posts. So far I can access the permalink page of the custom posts, but they don't appear on the main index of posts made. I was wondering if it was possible to make the custom post types appear as part of the main post feed and how it is done if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from wordpress [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Write this in your theme folders functions.php file:

```
function add_post_type_home_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'your_custom_post_type' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_post_type_home_query' );
```

Don't forget to replace 'your_custom_post_type' with your actual post_type that you created.

Comment: TY this worked! I've been searching for days literally for an answer! tyvm!